# Tag Typo? [style-gude]

Tags: bug, tags, retagging

There's a tag named [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude). I'm fairly certain that's a typo of [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide), which is also a tag that already exists. Interestingly, [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude) has a description while [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide) does not, although more questions are tagged with [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide) than [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude).

If I'm correct and [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude) is a typo, then it should be burned, the description should be moved to [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide), and any question with the tag [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude) should be retagged with [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've applied the tag wiki to the correct [style-guide](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-guide) and have re-tagged the relevant questions.

The [style-gude](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-gude) tag will expire naturally overnight I believe, provided nobody re-uses it for other questions.